# Border radius disappears in when printing from Google Chrome (Mac/Yosemite)

Tags: css, google-chrome, pretty-print

I have an interesting problem with placing a border radius on an image. The radius works fine when the page is rendered in the browser, but doesn't work (full rectangular image is shown) when I try to print the page.

This the HTML syntax (CSS is inline so it's easy for you guys to see).

`<img style="padding:0;margin:0;border-radius: 75px;-moz-border-radius: 75px;-webkit-border-radius: 75px;border: 3px solid #f58d1e;" border="0" height="50" width="50" src="myimage.jpg"/>`

I'm using Mac/Yosemite and my version of Google Chrome is "Version 40.0.2214.94 (64-bit)"